# Loading multiple View controller in UIPageViewController - Swiping shows blank screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am loading multiple UIViewControllers in UIPageViewController with each UIViewController having their own navigation bar. I have implemented all the required data source and delegate methods for UIPageViewController and it showing up correctly.

But when I scroll my view controller horizontally, more often, I see a white blank screen instead of my view controller. Below is my code.

Any clue what could be wrong here.

PS: I tried by removing the IF condition in my `viewControllerForRequestID` method and returning a new controller every time. This works but then I end up with one view controller showing up twice in pagination.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)iPageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)iViewController {
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:self.selectedRequestIndex];

    if (self.selectedRequestIndex == 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSUInteger aNewSelectedRequestIndex = self.selectedRequestIndex - 1;
    NSString *aPreviousRequestID = [self.paginationRequestIDList[aNewSelectedRequestIndex] stringValue];

    self.selectedRequestIndex = aNewSelectedRequestIndex;
    self.selectedRequestID = aPreviousRequestID;

    return [self viewControllerForRequestID:self.selectedRequestID];
}


- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)iPageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)iViewController {
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:self.selectedRequestIndex];

    if (self.selectedRequestIndex == NSNotFound || self.selectedRequestIndex >= self.paginationRequestIDList.count - 1) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSUInteger aNewSelectedRequestIndex = self.selectedRequestIndex + 1;
    NSString *aNextRequestID = self.paginationRequestIDList[aNewSelectedRequestIndex];

    self.selectedRequestIndex = aNewSelectedRequestIndex;
    self.selectedRequestID = aNextRequestID;

    return [self viewControllerForRequestID:self.selectedRequestID];
}


- (MyNavigationViewController *)viewControllerForRequestID:(id)iRequestID {
    NSString *aRequestID = iRequestID;

    // Safe check to avoid numbers in request ID
    if (![iRequestID isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        aRequestID = [iRequestID stringValue];
    }

    @synchronized (self) {
        if ([self.viewControllers containsObjectForKey:iRequestID]) {
            MyNavigationViewController *aNavigationController = self.viewControllers[iRequestID];
            return aNavigationController;
        }

        MyDataModel *aRequestData = self.savedRequestData[iRequestID];
        MyDataModelController *aRequestInfoController = [[MyDataModelController alloc] initWithRequestData:aRequestData];
        aRequestInfoController.delegate = self;
        MyNavigationViewController *aNavigationController = [[MyNavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aRequestInfoController];

        [self.viewControllers setObject:aNavigationController forKey:iRequestID];

        return aNavigationController;
    }
}
```